# How can i initialize the Source Type from Lead to Opportunity

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, lead

It is possible to qualify a lead, when a lead is qualified a new opportunity is created.

In the lead dialog it is possible to fill in a Source Type and Source ID.

I want to fill in the opportunity I make from the lead, in this case: If I fill in a campaign for the lead, the opportunity made from that lead must have the same campaign filled in in the source fields.

The problem is, that I can't figure out the process flow of the Source type fields and how I can initialize the SourceTypeId field on the Opportunity.

I have tried searching through the methods on SourceTypeId, but it doesn't help me, can anyone clear this up for me? And where do I have to initialize the desired fields?

I am using AX2012 and the tables: smmLeadTable and SmmOpportunityTable.

Comment: Do you have any code you've started with? What are the tables you're working with, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the class: `smmCreateEntity`, method `initFromLead` sets the `SourceTypeId` on the `smmOpportunityTable` from the `smmLeadTable`.

Comment: Could you mark this answer as accepted? This makes it easier for other People to see which questions are already resolved.